# IE9 CSS float:left and right push content down

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, css-float

I have a problem with CSS `float` handling in IE9.Look at [partycypacjaobywatelska.pl](http://partycypacjaobywatelska.pl). In Firefox, Chrome, Opera etc. main page is displayed correctly whereas IE9 shows a white space between the header and the rest of content.

This space is triggered by two elements of classes left and right (their place in DOM: `body` -> `#wrapper` -> `#container` -> `.left`, `.right`). They have `float: left` and `float: right` set, respectively but, nonetheless, in IE9 they push the `.middle` div down. Setting `display: none` on them helps but I don't fully control when those divs gain content so it's not a feasible solution to me.

I tried to create a minimal example but [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FTMA5/) works fine in IE9. Any idea what might trigger the bug?

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: Not sure what the issue is - super strange. What happens if you throw a `clear: none;` on .middle? Or set a height on .middle?

Comment: Setting `height` changes nothing while adding `clear: none` pushes `.middle` down. If you enter IE9 DOM Inspector and click on the `.middle` node you will see that `.middle` isn't actually pushed down, it's made narrower because of these floats. Then the `.jimgMenu` inside the `.middle` has a much larger width and it's pushed down. If I set `clear: both` on `.middle`, `.middle` is pushed down, too (but still keeps its shorter width... weird). In Chrome/Firefox `.middle` has much greater width than in IE9 (it's overlapping `.left` and `.right` as opposed to IE9 where they're side by side).

Comment: OK, my workaround is to make sure there are no whitespace inside `.left` and `.right` in layout and set `display: none` on `.left:empty` and `.right:empty`. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Using IE's dev tools, .middle actually isn't being pushed, it's the .jimgMenu inside of it. If you remove the overflow: hidden on that, then you can see IE9 and Firefox behave the same. It's definitely the floats shifting the content area. Have you tried a clearfix instead of using the overflow?

Honestly, those .left and .right should probably be positioned absolutely if they are stuck to the sides like that though. What do they even contain? Why are they suppose to be floating behind the content? It's probably not the best way to structure the HTML.

Comment: Yeah, I wouldn't do it using floats myself. I didn't create this site, I just "inherited" it from sb else and I have to put it in order. Originally it even missed any DOCTYPE...

Disabling `overflow: hidden` would require me to change their position to absolute and position `.middle` differently. TBH I'm a little afraid of changing too much in the layout as I don't know what wild dragons are hiding in this code waiting to bite me.

I just don't understand why IE9 behave differently here than the rest of the world, any ideas?

Comment: Also, see my comment to my question, I described what I discovered in DOM Inspector etc.

Comment: Ah, one remark - `.left` and `.right` have to be positioned statically or relatively because they can be potentially higher than what's in middle and footer needs to be below them; `.middle` is the weirdly positioned element here.

Comment: BTW, if by clearfix you mean setting `clear: both` on `.middle` or `.jimgMenu` while disabling `overflow: hidden` on `.jimgMenu` then it doesn't help; `.jimgMenu` is still pushed down.

Comment: By clearfix I mean instead of .jimgMenu using overflow, to add a .jImgMenu:after { content: ''; clear:both; display: block; }